# If Else in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

```
delimiter //
create procedure LedgerPostingGetCurrentBalanceOfLedger(p_Ledgerid varchar(50),p_postingDate datetime)
begin 
    declare p_balance decimal(20,4);
        declare p_crdr bit ;
        declare p_debit decimal(20,4);
        declare p_credit decimal(20,4);

    create temporary table temp_l1(debit varchar(50),credit varchar(50));

    insert into temp_l1(debit,credit)
        select ifnull(sum(debit),0) as Expr1, ifnull(sum(credit),0) as Expr2
        from tbl_ledgerposting
        where (ledgerid = p_Ledgerid) and (date <= p_postingDate);

select p_debit = debit, p_credit = credit from temp_l1 ;

        if(p_debit < p_credit) then set p_balance = (p_credit - p_debit) ; set p_crdr = 'true';
        else if (p_debit > p_credit) set p_balance = (p_debit - p_credit) ; set p_crdr = 'false';
        else if (p_debit = p_credit) ;
        end if;
    select p_balance, 0 as p_balance, p_crdr as CrOrDr ;
end //
delimiter ;
```

### error shows

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set p_balance = (p_debit - p_credit_ ; set p_crdr = 'false'; else if (p' at line 18

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close with an ')' on that statement.

```
else if (p_debit > p_credit) set p_balance = (p_debit - p_credit_ ; set p_crdr = 'false';
```

should be

```
else if (p_debit > p_credit) set p_balance = (p_debit - p_credit) ; set p_crdr = 'false';
```

Comment: still error ..
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; line 18

Comment: compilar is showing error on line below...
      
if(p_debit < p_credit) then set p_balance = (p_credit - p_debit) ; set p_crdr = 'true';